# log4php: How to change database name / db host / username dynamically in XML?

Tags: php, logging, log4php

I have a case where I might be having multiple DBs and each DB will have it's own log table.

Since I'm using DBAppender in a log4php.xml, how do I change dynamically (on rumtime) change the database name and/or db host. Is there any possibility to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure log4php at runtime using a PHP array instead of an XML configuration, as show in log4php doc :

http://logging.apache.org/log4php/docs/configuration.html

Comment: thanks @adrien ... I almost ignore PHP config and focused on XML. It worked, thank you :)